# Overlap and merge two pages of a PDF

Tags: linux, pdf, merge, vector-graphics

In a PDF document, two adjacent A4 pages contain a graph in a vector format: the first page contains the left half of the graph, the second page contains the right half. These two halves should be merged in a unique, larger A3 page

Moreover, I need to move the two pages horizontally before creating the A3 sheet, because they have a little, common strip.

Is there a way to do this in Linux?

As stated in the comments below, I tried Libreoffice Draw, but there the elements of the graph appear in a messy arrangement when the first page is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

[LibreOffice Draw](https://www.libreoffice.org/discover/draw/) can [edit pdf documents](https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/tr-dojo/edit-pdf-documents-with-libreoffice-draw/), as well as [Ableword](http://www.ableword.net/index.html).

I have not used Ableword, I know LibreOffice Draw can do what you want, although LibreOffice can be very slow with large PDF's.

Comment: I tried Libreoffice Draw, but all the elements of this graph are not correctly re-drawn by that program: they appeared in a messy arrangement.

Comment: Have tried any other programs?  http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfsam/ ?

Comment: Have you tried the Gimp?  https://www.gimp.org/about/introduction.html

Answer (score 0):

NitroPDF is a great PDFtool, you can grab a 30day trial to do what you need to do.

https://www.gonitro.com/

Comment: Nitro is not available for Linux and doesn't do anything close to what this user is asking for.